# Can I convert a My.Resources file into a Properties.Resources file

Tags: c#, vb.net

I already have an existing My.Resources File, I would like to convert to a Properties.Resources file.  I wouldn't want to do it by hand (that could get ugly).  Is there a tool out there that is capable of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

The `My.Resources` type is really just a standard `.resx` file that exists in your project.  This is exactly the same format that C# uses and can be copied directly from one project to the other.

The `.resx` file will be under the `My Project` folder of your project.  The easiest way to import it over is to

- Right click on the C# project
- Add -> Existing Item
- Navigate to the vb.net `.resx` file and select it

Comment: It is already added, but there are certain entries which aren't compatible with my current project...
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0"), System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(), Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute()]  
That for instance.  All of a sudden I am forgetting, is a Properties.Resource File a .resx file as well?